# dynamic variable inserted from PHP into DOM. Having trouble passing that variable from DOM to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a system where people can vote on answers to a question.

The answers are fetched from a database then displayed in a foreach.

For the voting system I need to pass certain variables into JS to the do some AJAX magic with, however i'm falling at the first hurdle of just passing the variables to JS.

At the moment the code looks like such:

```
<?php
            if ($answers->num_rows() == 0) {
                echo '<p>Be the first to answer this question!</p>';
            } else {
                foreach ($answers->result() as $row)
                {
                    echo '<div class="answers-to-question">';
                    echo '<form>'; //form for the purpose of voting
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="a_id" value="'.$row->a_id.'">'; //pass this to voting script
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="u_id" value="'.$row->username.'">'; //pass this to voting script
                    echo '<pre>'.$row->answer.'</pre>';
                    echo '<p class="green">answered '.$row->timestamp.' by <i class="green">'.$row->username.'</i></p>';
                    echo '<input type="button" name="upvote" value="upvote" onClick="upvote(this.form.u_id);">';
                    echo '</form>';
                    echo '</div>';

                }
            }               
            ?>
```

So I have a button which on click should pass the variables in a JS function

**Button**

```
echo '<input type="button" name="upvote" value="upvote" onClick="upvote(this.form.u_id);">';
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        function upvote(username){

            console.log(username);

        }
    });
```

This isn't working and i'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function   onClick
```

If it helps, i'm using the Codeigniter and JQuery frameworks

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Your input is named `upvote`. Internet Exploder has the wonderful idiocy of automatically creating top-level objects named the same as each `name` attribute in your form. so `onclick="upvote(...)"` is not calling your function, it's tryign to call your INPUT as if it was a function.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, I see. So how do I get it to refer to a function within my <script> tags?

Comment: change the name of your function, or of the input, to something that's not used elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it all with jQuery instead of using inline JavaScript -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function upvote(username){
        console.log(username);
    }

    $('input[name="upvote"]').click(function() {
        var username = $(this).parent('form').find('[name="u_id"]').val();
        upvote(username);
    });
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/05ojohmg/)

Here is an [UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/05ojohmg/1/) sending two variables to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for adding some information, the code had two problems:

1. You were calling your function the same that your button, so that was why the message said that it wasn't a function, it was an element.
2. The function was declared inside de .ready() statement, so the function didn't exist. You must declare it before the ready() statement.